# Difference between h:commandLink and p:menuItem

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I already asked the question differently and it was answered as duplicate and the answer should be found in [commandButton issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value).
I tried following all tipps, but in first place, the p:menuItem isn't really used in the examples and second in Debug Hints it apears that something is triggered, but I can't see what an my breakpoint at the beginning of the called method is never reached.

So I think I'm going to post way more code. This is the jsf-implementation which works:

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="menu.css"/>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <h:commandLink value="Status" immediate="true" 
                action="status.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" />
        </li>
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{aduserHandler.isAdmin}">
            <li>
                <h:commandLink value="Einstellungen"  immediate="true" 
                    action="parameter.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" />
            </li>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <li>
            <h:commandLink value="Abmelden"  immediate="true" 
                action="#{aduserHandler.logout}" />
        </li>
     </ul>
</ui:composition>
```

Both methods isAdmin() and logout() are triggered and performed correctly.

This is the primefaces-implementation which isn't working:

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">


    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="menu.css"/>

    <h:form id="menuform">
        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
        <div class="card">
            <h5>Menu</h5>
            <p:menu>
                <p:submenu label="ATC">
                    <p:menuitem value="Status" 
                        url="/atc/status.xhtml" 
                        icon="pi pi-list"/>
                </p:submenu>
                <p:submenu label="KV">
                </p:submenu>
                <p:submenu label="Einstellung">
                    <p:menuitem value="Einstellungen" 
                        url="/atc/parameter.xhtml" 
                        icon="pi pi-cog"
                        rendered="#{aduserHandler.isAdmin}"/>
                    <p:menuitem value="Abmelden" 
                        action="#{aduserHandler.logout}" 
                        icon="pi-directions-alt"/>
                </p:submenu>
            </p:menu>
        </div>
    </h:form>
    <h:commandLink value="Abmelden" immediate="true" action="#{aduserHandler.logout}" />
</ui:composition>
```

For testing purpose I even added the h:commandLink out of the first implementation but the logout() methode is in neither one of the buttons triggered. But to make it really weird, the isAdmin() methode works perfectly.

I tried menuitem with `update="@form"` and `update="menuform"` but neither worked.

I really want to understand how those menuitems work, because I wanted to use the possibility to code the menu in a class.

References to an own jQuery import have been deleted.

Edit:
You were completely right. I've made the first attempt out of my JSF 101-Book and didn't realize that my layout.xhmtl goes like:

```
<html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />
    <title>Asset Tool Connector</title>
        <link type="image/x-icon"
            href="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/images/netzwerk.png"
            rel="shortcut icon" />
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <ui:insert name="header"/>
    <f:event listener="#{aduserHandler.checkLoggedIn}" type="preRenderView" />
    <h:form>
        <div id="menu">
            <ui:include src="menu.xhtml" />
        </div>

        <div id="main">
            <ui:insert name="main"/>
        </div>
    </h:form>   
    <div id="footer">
        &#169; ATC - by 5332
    </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

But if I hadn't asked I had not looked anyway. Now what is better code for Primefaces? To leave the form around everything or to open a own form for every let's call it button group or function.

Comment: I noticed you have `immediate="true"` on your CommandLinks but not on your MenuItems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is that in the second case you have a `h:form` embedded within another `h:form`. (Point 2 on the list from @BalusC). I can't validate this because the calling code hasn't been posted, but it is suspicious when the code snippet for `h:commandLink` doesn't include a form but needs one to work correctly, yet the PrimeFaces snippet does.

I'd also guess that the error is not apparent because in web.xml the `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` parameter is not set to `Development`, meaning some warnings and errors are suppressed. See the first part of BalusC's list.

There are also probably no error handlers defined in your faces-config.xml file, which also means some errors get suppressed. See https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/core/errorhandling.

When I replicate these circumstances in a simple JSF application using PrimeFaces 8 and Wildfly 21, I can see similar symptons to those you describe.